# Why does the API not return photos and albums which are visible to the authenticated user? (Has friends_photos permission)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos

**Edit: Made an [official bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/317822564919138?fb_comment_id=fbc_10150514573283666_31285393_10150514574958666&ref=notif&notif_t=open_graph_comment#u2kzqt_3) at developers.Facebook.com**

GETing either of the following:

`graph.facebook.com/me/photos`
`graph.facebook.com/me/albums`

returns lots of photos.

GETing:

`graph.facebook.com/1146720040/photos`
`graph.facebook.com/1146720040/albums`

Returns:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

1146720040 is a friend, and I **DO** have the **friends_photos** permission. I've tried this with ~10 different users, all friends, and none have returned any photos. All of the users have photos I can see when I browse to facebook.com.

Why is the API not returning photos and albums that are visible in the browser?

**PS:** I'm using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ to test the queries, in case that matters.

Comment: +1 Your mistake gave me the right hint how to get the users tagged photos XD - thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `graph.facebook.com/[user_id]/photos` returns photos that user is tagged in, for that user.  AFAIK you can't use it to retrieve anyone's photos but the logged in users.

You need to use `graph.facebook.com/[album_id]/photos` to get friend's photos.

To get there from user you have to get a list of `album_ids` from an individual friend.

Comment: For the friends which return no photos at `/[friend_id]/photos`, the `/albums` endpoint also responds with an empty set: http://cl.ly/1V2j3v1q3C351C1x0a26  When a friend has results at `/albums` they also have results at `/photos`

Comment: There's an additional security setting you can set within facebook to restrict friends access to your photos, regardless of what permissions your friends grant.  You will not be able to get these user's photos.  Check yourself: FB > Privacy > Apps > How people bring your info to apps they use

Comment: I am able to get /albums of friends but I am getting empty data array for /[friend_id]/photos. I have permissions as well user_photos. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 2):

Your application is not having access permission . You need user_photos permission to access

photo details

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. Check this site and create a temporary access token use that hardcoded value and check. It ll work